# Data conversion failed in SQL Server replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, transactional-replication

I am newbie to SQL Server. I have a transactional replication setup in my production environment. I am getting the below error while replicating from publisher to subscriber.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '* ' to data type int.
>   Error: 14151, Severity: 18, State: 1.

Kindly help me to fix this in replication setup.

Comment: what couldn't you understand in that error?  `'* '` is not a valid data to cast from varchar to int.

Comment: I am new to sql server.So what i need to do fix this in replication @Sankar Raj

Comment: if you are really not sure then try using try_parse to convert data from varchar to int.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: for publisher and subscriber sql server 2008(SP4) @SankarRaj

Comment: @Viking `try_parse` is available only from SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL SERVER 2008, You can use below query snippet to avoid this error

```
 SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(@data) = 1 THEN CAST(@data AS int)
    ELSE NULL
  END
```

Comment: How does that help the OP with their replication problem exactly?